# The delete function deletes all elements of the collection in Firestore Database

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

In the application I'm working on, the user has the option of entering their own data into Firestore. After that, this data is uploaded to AccountScreen in the form of an image and title. I am trying to implement the ability for the user to delete the data from the AccountScreen after pressing the X icon. After that, he is asked if he is sure he wants to clear the data. After clicking yes, all elements from the AccountScreen are deleted, not just the selected ones. What do I need to change in the code to delete only the selected item?

My delete function:

```
fun deleteProjectFromFirestore(db: FirebaseFirestore, currentUserUid: String, callback: (Boolean) -> Unit) {
        db.collection("user_projects")
            .document(currentUserUid)
            .collection("projects")
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { it ->
                for (document in it) {
                    db.collection("user_projects")
                        .document(currentUserUid)
                        .collection("projects")
                        .document(document.id).delete().addOnSuccessListener {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Project deleted")
                        }
                }
                callback(true)
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                Log.e(ContentValues.TAG, "Error deleting project", e)
                callback(false)
            }
    }
```

My AccountScreen:

```
@Composable
fun AccountScreen(homeViewModel: HomeViewModel = viewModel(),
                  accountViewModel: AccountViewModel = viewModel()) {

    accountViewModel.getUserData()
    val userUid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.uid
    val db = Firebase.firestore
    val projectsListState = remember { mutableStateOf<List<ProjectData>>(emptyList()) }
    val scrollState = rememberScrollState()
    var loadingInProgress = mutableStateOf(true)
    var showDialog by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    Scaffold (
        topBar = {
            AppToolbar(toolbarTitle = stringResource(id = R.string.app_name),
                logoutButtonClicked = {
                    homeViewModel.logout()
                })
        },
        bottomBar = {
            AppBottomNavigation(
                selectedTab = Screen.AccountScreen,
                onTabSelected = { /* Handle tab selection */ }
            )
        }
    ) { paddingValues ->
        Surface (
            color = colorResource(id = R.color.colorPrimary),
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .background(colorResource(id = R.color.colorPrimary))
                .padding(paddingValues)
                .verticalScroll(scrollState)
        ) {
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth(), horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.End
            ) {
                Icon(
                    imageVector = Icons.Default.Settings,
                    contentDescription = stringResource(id = R.string.settings),
                    tint = colorResource(id = R.color.colorWhite),
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .size(43.dp)
                        .padding(top = 8.dp, end = 14.dp)
                        .clickable {
                            SewingAppRouter.navigateTo(Screen.SettingsScreen)
                        }
                )
            }

            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(16.dp)
                    .fillMaxWidth(),
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
            ) {
                Image(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .size(150.dp) // Set the size of the image
                        .padding(vertical = 16.dp), // Add vertical padding
                    imageVector = Icons.Filled.AccountCircle,
                    contentDescription = null,
                    colorFilter = ColorFilter.tint(Color.White)
                )
                TextComponent(value = accountViewModel.emailId?.value ?: "")
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(80.dp))
                AddTextComponent(value = stringResource(id = R.string.my_projects))

                Button(onClick = {
                    SewingAppRouter.navigateTo(Screen.AddProjectScreen)
                }, modifier = Modifier
                    .align(Alignment.Start)
                    .padding(5.dp),
                    colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
                        containerColor = Color.White,
                        contentColor = colorResource(id = R.color.colorPrimary))) {
                    Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.addNew))
                }

                accountViewModel.retriveDataFromFirestore(db, userUid.toString()) { projects ->
                    projectsListState.value = projects
                    loadingInProgress.value = false
                }

                if (!loadingInProgress.value) {
                    for (project in projectsListState.value) {
                        val imagePainter = rememberImagePainter(data = project.image)
                        val title = "${project.title ?: ""}"

                        Box(modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth(0.5f)
                            .padding(16.dp)) {
                            accountViewModel.ImageCard(
                                painter = imagePainter,
                                contentDescription = null,
                                title = title,
                                onCloseClicked = {
                                    showDialog = true
                                }
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }
                else {
                    CircularProgressIndicator()
                }

                if (showDialog) {
                    AlertDialog(
                        onDismissRequest = {
                            showDialog = false
                        },
                        title = {
                            Text(text = "Deleting project")
                        },
                        text = {
                            Text(text = "Are you sure you want to delete your project?")
                        },
                        confirmButton = {
                            Button(
                                onClick = {
                                    showDialog = false
                                },
                                colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(containerColor = colorResource(
                                    id = R.color.colorPrimary
                                ), contentColor = Color.White
                                )
                            ) {
                                Text(text = "No")
                            }
                        },
                        dismissButton = {
                            Button(
                                onClick = {
                                    accountViewModel.deleteProjectFromFirestore(db, userUid.toString()) { success ->
                                        if(success) {
                                            showDialog = false
                                        }
                                        else {
                                            Log.e(TAG, "Project deletion failed")
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(containerColor = colorResource(
                                    id = R.color.colorPrimary
                                ), contentColor = Color.White
                                )
                            ) {
                                Text(text = "Yes")
                            }
                        }
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
    SystemBackButtonHandler {
        SewingAppRouter.navigateTo(Screen.AccountScreen)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to know for which project the delete dialog is shown, so instead of

```kotlin
var showDialog by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
```

you can have this:

```kotlin
var deletedProjectId by remember { mutableStateOf<String?>(null) }
```

your code will then look like this:

```kotlin
for (project in projectsListState.value) {
  ImageCard(
    onCloseClick = { deletedProjectId = project.id },
  )
}

if (deletedProjectId != null) {
  AlertDialog(
    dismissButton = {
      Button(
        onClick = {
          deleteProjectFromFirestore(db, userUid, deletedProjectId) { success ->
            if (success) deletedProjectId = null
          }
        }
      )
    }
  )
}
```